# How to import multiple USERS access-rights to multiple Mailboxes using Powershell CSV or Text File

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I`m looking to improve an existing code as mentioned below.
As you can see it does basic Add-MailboxPermissio & Add-RecipientPermission
Actions.

USERS are being added from a TXT file
While mailbox names are being entered manually each time

What i am looking to do is to import the mailboxes names from a TXT file 
So i can add users permissions to multiple mailboxes.

Your help is most appreciated !

```
$Users = Get-Content "C:\powershell\permmisions\Users.txt"
$Users | %{Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "mailboxname@address.com" -User $_ -AccessRights Fullaccess -AutoMapping:$true}
$Users | %{Add-RecipientPermission -Identity "mailboxname@address" -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee $_ -Confirm:$false }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with two TXT files and two foreach loops.

```
$Users = Get-Content "C:\powershell\permissions\Users.txt"
$Mailboxes = Get-Content "C:\powershell\permissions\mailboxes.txt"

foreach ($user in $Users) {
    foreach ($mailbox in $Mailboxes) {
        Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $mailbox -User $user -AccessRights Fullaccess -AutoMapping:$true
        Add-RecipientPermission -Identity $mailbox -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee $user -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```

The solution assumes that your **mailboxes.txt** file contains the mailbox identifiers that you can pass into the `-Identity` parameters of your commands. You could populate `$Mailboxes` another way besides reading a text file as long as the variable is a collection.

Comment: Yup, That does it. Thanks a bunch !